# MongoDB Error MongoServerError: bad auth : Authentication failed

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongoose

Hi How is it going so can you help me please I get some error when I'am connecting mongoDB using shell

below is the error command   ↓

```
MongoServerError: bad auth : Authentication failed.
```

- ##### OS = Ubuntu 64 bit
- ##### Motherboard = gigabyte H510M

I have try many time until I download vscode extension but yeah it's not working

Comment: Can you connect to the server with `mongosh` or `MongoDB Compass`?  What connection string are you using?

Comment: How do you try to connect?

Comment: It's not error now thanks everyone Regards.